# Couchbase on Nodejs - how the add () method works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchbase, nosql

It's a basic question but i'm learning couchbase now and in my fail i'm trying to insert Data into my couchbase instance with the add() method. But something in my code doesnt work well and i dont know why.

```
var http = require("http");

var driver = require('couchbase');
var cb = new driver.Cluster("127.0.0.1:8091", null, null, "default");
var server = http.createServer(insertData);



console.log ("BA4KAAAAA!!");

function insertData() {
    var emps = [{
        "type": "employee",
        "id": 100,
        "name": "Anton",
        "dept": "Sales",
        "salary": 5000
    }, {
        "type": "employee",
        "id": 200,
        "name": "Ivan",
        "dept": "IT",
        "salary": 3000
    }, {
        "type": "employee",
        "id": 300,
        "name": "Petko",
        "dept": "Manager",
        "salary": 10000


}]
    for (index = 0; index< emps.lenght; index++) {
        cb.add(JSON.stringify(emps[index].id), JSON.stringify(emps[index]), 0, undefined, function(data, err, key, cas ) {
            if (err&&err != 12) {
                console.log("FAIL!" + err);
            }
        });
    }
}

server.listen(8080, insertData());
```

I run the server and the console says it works but nothing changes into my CB Admin tool.

Comment: The question was also asked on the [Couchbase forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/something-wrong-into-my-add-method/2772)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a spelling mistake at the start of the for loop: `emps.lenght` should be `emps.length`.

**length** was spelt wrong.